# JSON array element count

Tags: jquery, json

this is my json array i need the count of projectid(not length of the array) .i am expecting count is 2 because the

```js
[{

 "oid": "1",
 "oname": "Fontbyte",
 "bun": [{
  "projectid": "1",
  "bname": "euuu",
  "dep": [{
   "did": "1",
   "dname": "Development department"


  }, {
   "did": "2",
   "dname": "prod"

  }]
 }, {
  "projectid": "2",
  "bname": "USs",
  "dep": []
 }]
}]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

array have 2 projectid.how it is possible jquery or javascript?

Comment: Have you tried something ? Like a `foreach in array -> has projectid ?`

Comment: So you don't tried anything ? This is not exactly how Stackoverlow works...

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop the object like:

```
count = 0;
$.each(obj[0].bun,function(i,v){
 $.each(v,function(x,t){
 if (x == 'projectid') {
 count+=1
 };
 });
});
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to initialize a variable with *zero*.

```
var count = 0;
```

Post that, you need to run a loop, which checks and increments the same:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].bun.length; i++) { /* 'data' is the object which stores the data */
    if (data[0].bun[i].projectid) {
      count += 1;
    }
}
```

Find the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ojq64pkx/).

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the items that have the `projectid` property are located in the object, you could do:

```
var n = 0;
obj[0].bun.forEach(function(item){ if (item.projectid != null) n++});
```

If you don't, it would be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use a recursive function to find the occurrence of a key in the json
    function walk(obj,keyname) {    
        var propertyCount=0;                                                                                    
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var val = obj[key];                                                                         
                    if(typeof(val) == 'object') {                                                                                                                   
                        propertyCount += walk(val,keyname);                                             
                    }else {
                        if(key == keyname){                                                     
                            propertyCount +=1;                  
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }   
            return propertyCount;                               
    }
    alert(walk(obj,'projectid'));//obj is your json array
    It will return 2
```